# Captured Variable in Lambda Task Not Updating

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a list of headlines that I am trying to process by using a Task that updates a parameter of the headline object. The code I am trying to do it with does not actually populate the parameter properly. When I debug it, I can see that the setters are being activated and properly updating the backing fields, but when examined after Task.WhenAll , none of the properties are in fact set to their expected values.

```
//**Relevant signatures are:**
    class Headline{
        public Uri Uri { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> AttachedEmails { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }


    async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetEmailsFromHeadline(Uri headlineUri) {
        //bunch of async fetching logic that populates emailNodes correctly


        return emailNodes.Select(e => e.InnerText).ToList();
    }



//**Problem Area**

//Initiate tasks that start fetching information
        var taskList = 
            postData
                .Select(e => new HttpRequest() { Uri = actionUri, PostData = e })
                .Select(e => Task.Run(() => GetHeadlines(e)))
                .ToList();

//Wait till complete
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

//Flatten list 
        var allHeadlines = 
            taskList
                .SelectMany(e => e.Result.ToList());

//After this section of code I expect every member AttachedEmails property to be properly updated but this is not what is happening. 

            var headlineProcessTaskList =
                allHeadlines
                    .Select(e => Task.Run( new Func<Task>( async () => e.AttachedEmails = await GetEmailsFromHeadline(e.Uri) ) ) )
                    .ToList();

             await Task.WhenAll(headlineProcessTaskList);
```

Comment: Is `allHeadlines` data in memory? Or does it fetch new data when enumerated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't enough code to reproduce the problem. However, we can guess that:

```
allHeadlines is IEnumerable<Headline>
```

Since this is `IEnumerable<T>`, it is *possible* that it is a LINQ query that has been deferred. Thus, when you enumerate it once in the `ToList` call, it creates `Headline` instances that have their `AttachedEmails` set. But when you enumerate it *again* later, it creates new `Headline` instances.

If this is correct, then one solution would be to change the type of `allHeadlines` to `List<Headline>`.

A similar problem could occur in `GetEmailsFromHeadline`, which presumably returns `Task<IEnumerable<string>>` and not `IEnumerable<string>` as stated. If the enumerable is deferred, then the only asynchronous part is *defining* the query; *executing* it would be after the fact - more specifically, outside the `Task.Run`. You might want to consider using `ToList` there, too.

On a side note, the `new Func` is just noise, and the wrapping of an asynchronous task in `Task.Run` is quite unusual. This would be more idiomatic:

```
 var headlineProcessTaskList =
    allHeadlines
        .Select(async e => e.AttachedEmails = await GetEmailsFromHeadline(e.Uri) )
        .ToList();
```

or, if the `Task.Run` is truly necessary:

```
 var headlineProcessTaskList =
    allHeadlines
        .Select(e => Task.Run( () => e.AttachedEmails = (await GetEmailsFromHeadline(e.Uri)).ToList() ) )
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen for responding within the limited information I provided. I have edited the question to be a bit more explanatory. After reading what you wrote, I took another look at how allHeadlines is populating and it seems that you were in fact right when suggesting that I wasnt resolving the linq query causing it to be rerun on every usage. It is now updating as expected. To address your Func noise comment, I put it there to keep the signature as Task, and not Task<IEnumerable<string>>, because the lambda didnt actually return anything and I wasnt sure how Task.Result gets populated.